# Adding event listners to a string and then converting it to an html/react element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that splits and checks for a word that matches the regex.. and if word found it add it in a span tag and style it then parse it using react parser..

```
const checkContent = (content) => {
    content = content.split(' ')
    let tag = '<p>'
    content.map(word => {
      if(word.match(regex))
        tag += ` <span className="taggedUser">${word}</span> `
      else
        tag += ' ' + word
    })
    tag += '</p>'
    return ( parse(`<div>${tag}</div>`))
  }
```

However i'm having difficulty trying to add an event listner to it like OnClick().
The only solution I've come up with is adding the listners by js via addEventListner().
My question is there any other way other than the above mentioned. Adding the listner directly to the span tag like this `<span OnClick={handleClick} className="tagged">${word}</span>` and then returning it?? Any ideas??

Comment: While React doesn't do event delegation in the normal sense (it adds all the listeners to the root regardless of what element they're on) you can still use the principle. Add the `onClick` handler to the containing element of where you're adding your spans instead of on the spans themselves, and then have that watch for the events from its children.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding onClick=${} or onClick={} directly to the span on line 6? I don't think it will actually work and I believe if you are using parse like this, from a library, to parse a react component you will need to add listeners via addEventListener().

Comment: yea. i tried adding it on line 6... and as you said it doesn't work it displays the onClick() event as an actual string..

Comment: Check out Andy's comment, I think that may be your best bet :)